# Terraform, Archive failed due to missing directory

Tags: azure, directory, terraform, devops

I have been working on Terraform using AzureDevOps before that I developed tf files using VS code and everything worked fine when try to move files from VS code to Azure DevOps , getting issue on Archive source file path it unable to find the directory, searched every where but unable to resolve this,

Path which was working fine on VS code was “…/Folder name” using same path in Azure DevOps as I have upload completed folder that I have build in VS code but it always get failed when try to archive files as it un-able to find the directory.

[Code Block DevOps]

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      # Root module should specify the maximum provider version
      # The ~> operator is a convenient shorthand for allowing only patch releases within a specific minor release.
      version = "~>2.11"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  #skip_provider_registration = true
}

locals {
  location = "uksouth"
}

data "archive_file" "file_function_app" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../BlobToBlobTransferPackage"
  output_path = "blobtoblobtransfer-app.zip"
}

module "windows_consumption" {
  source = "./modules/fa"

  archive_file = data.archive_file.file_function_app
}

output "windows_consumption_hostname" {
  value = module.windows_consumption.function_app_default_hostname
}
```

Image of VS Code where everything is working fine:
[image]
Image of DevOps where getting Missing Directory Error:
[image]

[Folder Structure that is working fine with VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wURYJ.png)

Comment: Please do not post code nor errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: I have posted what I am facing also explained everything in detail, hope that's help.

Comment: The path is wrong. Are you trying to zip the same directory you are running Terraform from?

Comment: No that is the different directory, there are two folders one has TF files and other one having package file that need to be zipped, it always return directory not found.

Comment: I don't see that directory in the VSCode screenshot.

Comment: In VS Code one folder contains two folder one for tf file and one for package file.

Comment: Since I don't see the directory structure in VSCode, I would suggest doing something like `${path.root}/../BlobToBlobTransferPackage`.

Comment: I have updated the question with VS code folder structure which is working fine but at Azure DevOps it saying missing directory

Comment: My comment still stands. Since you might be working on different operating systems, using `path` should be a lot of help.

Comment: when using ${path.root}/../BlobToBlobTransferPackage  it becomes this ./../BlobToBlobTransferPackage and error remains same

Answer (score 0):

It was due to path which is fixed now,